# How to find the number of real roots of this polynomial with regards to a real parameter?

Tags: calculus

Let $m \in \mathbb{R}$, $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^4 - 6x^2 + mx + 24$.

Determine the number of real roots of $f$.

What I tried was to find out the local maximums/minimums of $f$ from $f'$.

$f'(x) = 4x^3 - 12x + m$, this is a cubic equation and I cannot use the cubic equation formula to find out the roots so I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $g(x) = x^3 - 6 x + 24/x$.  A root of $f$ is a root of $g(x) + m$.

The only real roots of $g'(x)$ are $x=2$ and $x=-2$.  For $-\infty < x \le 2$,
$g$ increases from $-\infty$ to $g(-2) = -8$, for $2 \le x < 0$, it decreases to $-\infty$.
Similarly, $g$ decreases from $+\infty$ to $g(2)=8$, then increases to $+\infty$.

So there are two roots of $f$ if $m < -8$ or $m > 8$, there is one if $m = \pm 8$, and there are none if $-8 < m < 8$.